# Dialogue usage uncertainty

Tags: grammaticality, dialogue

Sorry for the vague title! I'm writing a short story and I'm wondering if the below sentence is correct. Should a new paragraph be started when she hears the shout, since it's technically dialogue? Or is it okay as is?

> Amelia dragged a chair onto the balcony, and enjoyed the fresh air while ignoring the shout of, “You broke a string already?!” below. She placed the book on the edge and. . .

I'll be happy to provide more context if it is needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: ...while ignoring the shout "You broke a string already?!” below. I think, 'of' after shout may be ignored. Look, it can be written in a number of ways; what matters is author's discretion; and in creative writing, little things shouldn't matter.

Comment: *Amelia dragged a chair onto the balcony, and enjoyed the fresh air while ignoring a shout from below: “You broke a string already?!” She placed the book on the edge and...* Or *Amelia dragged a chair onto the balcony, enjoying the fresh air. A voice from below shouted, “You broke a string already?!" which she ignored. She placed the book on the edge and...* You don't need a new paragraph unless a conversation happens.